# by tracking its Infinity Recursive- JAVA basic q -, cant understand why its not recursive and how i tried to track this

Tags: java, loops, recursion, return, infinity

```
public static int sod2(int x) {
    if(x<10)
        return 0;
    return sod2(x/10)*10 + (x%10);
    }
}
```

I can not understand how its not infinity recursive, tried some different numbers and track it by myself it always leads me to the same exact number, however the code output is working and showing all of the digits apart from the first digit. thankes for helping (for number that bigger than 10)

Comment: What do you see if you are debugging it?

Comment: when im debugging with some random number its showing the output and disconecting debugging

Comment: If you analyze what the debugger shows you, does it follow the logic you expect it to do?

Comment: im sorry im begginer and i dont really understand the debuggin stuff, i tried to run the code in some java online code runner and it has debug option next to the run button and when i press it its just give me the output and disconnecting gdb.

Comment: Do you have an IDE, like eclipse or intellij? Those have an integrated debugger. Debugging is a vital technique to learn.

Comment: The code is working for me with no bugs just cant understand the logic of the output, according to my stupidity and caculating it by myself its seems to be infinity recursive but the code runner shows otherwise and im trying to understand the logic of why it is not recursive.

Comment: It is definitely recursive, it is not _infinitely_ recursive because of the default case that will always return `0` when `x<10`.  `x` will always be eventually less than `10` because every time you call the method recursively, the input is getting divided by 10.

Comment: how the input is getting divided by 10? when i caculate it and tried to print this line alone for example 123: System.out.println((123/10)*10 + (123%10)) - the output is still 123

Comment: i mean the method is calling for itself again with the same x number.

Comment: maybe i just dont understand the call for the method so well?? cuz it seems to lead to the same input again.

Comment: It gets divided by 10 here: `sod2(x/10)`  every time this method is recursively called.  You are printing the entire line, not what you are passing to the method.  The rest of that line is completely irrelevant to the recursive call.  For example if your `x` is `123` as you said, that means you are calling `sod2(123/10)`.

Comment: owwww if the call was with another () like:     return sod2((x/10)*10 + (x%10)); - all of the line would be relevant??

Comment: I think you are greatly confusing yourself by adding math with a method call.  Whatever is inside the method call is what is relevant.  You use parenthesis to indicate a method call, but you also use it for math which is what you are getting confused with.  Anything inside of `sod2()` is what is passed.  In the original problem that is only `sod2(x /10)`, so yes of course if you add more things into the method call it will affect the method: `sod2(x / 10 + 10)` is obviously different.  You are doing something like `sod2( (x/10) + 10)` which has both math and a method call using parenthesis.

Comment: I think you need to take the time and go through through it step by step with a pen and paper or something and write down what is happening at every step, you are just missing some fundamental understanding that is hard to explain.

Comment: For example you tried to print `(123/10)*10 + (123%10)` to see what the value is, but you are not even printing the correct thing.  `sod2(123/10)` is NOT the same thing as `(123/10)`

Comment: thank you so much im so dumb for this, you are obviously right got confused with the math, finally understood, but its really weird that the rest of the line that not included in the method call is not showing any error or somthing i will try to track the code now ty very much.

Comment: There is no error because there should be no error.  `sod(123/10)` will return an integer and THAT value will be used in the math.  Basically `sod2(x/10)*10 + (x%10)` will be `theNumberReturned*10 + (x%10)`

Comment: the -System.out.println((123/10)*10 + (123%10)) - just thought i was mistaken with the math or somthing, in the code i used System.out.println(sod2(123)); but thank you so much for helping

Comment: so theNumberReturned*10 + (x%10) will happen only after the the last time when num<10?

Comment: Yeah exactly, it will hit the bottom case where `num < 10`, return the value back up, do math with that value, return ITS value back and then all the method calls will go back up with their values the same way as it might have been recursively called many times.  Basically it goes all the way down with the method calls first until it hits the `num < 10` case, then goes backwards back up.